# Having this issue :Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Tags: c#, android, listview

this is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace inicio
{
    [Activity(Label = "Respostas")]
    public class Respostas : ListActivity 
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Respostas);
            TextView txtnome = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView2);
            ListView list = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.list);
            string text = Intent.GetStringExtra("Nome") ?? "Data not available";
            txtnome.Text = text;
            var lista_respostas = Intent.Extras.GetStringArrayList("Respostas") ?? new string[0];

            list.Adapter= new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, lista_respostas);



        }
    }
}
```

and this is my axml page code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:text="Bem Vindo,"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView1" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />
    <ListView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/list" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Every time i try to run my programm is getting this issue:Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Note that i'm using C# for android on Visual Studio

Can someone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Already asked on #SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `ListActivity` you must use the `list` ID provided by the Android SDK on your `ListView`.

Change `android:id="@+id/list"` to `android:id="@android:id/list"`

Comment: if i change to that when i do this :ListView list = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.???); cant find my list view

Comment: You need to import the resource provided by Android. I'm not a c# guy, so I'm not sure what the namespace is, but I'm sure you'll be able to find it quickly.

Comment: I only posted this, beacuse i wanted someone who knows well c# could answer me, anyway thank you @Danail Alexiev

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with c#. It's all related to the Android platform. If you try something like `Android.Resource.Id.List` you should be able to find what you need.